# Win32 C++ - Memcpy Function - Access violation error

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, memcpy, portable-executable

I am making a self-extracting program, which essentially gets a pointer to the data being extracted (hardcoded) and adds it to a buffer, from which I shall perform operations upon,

However, I have encountered a problem, I seem to be getting a buffer-overrun error from my memcpy function, I have tried memcpy_s, but same problem occurs:

I can't really understand why the function is not working, as I am moving data to a allocated area in memory with the correct size,

```
LPVOID ExtractPayload(HINSTANCE _hInstance)
{
DWORD m_ptr = NULL;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS m_pntHeader;
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER m_pdosHeader;
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER m_psectionHeader;
m_pdosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)_hInstance;   // we don't need to make checks
m_pntHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)m_pdosHeader + m_pdosHeader->e_lfanew);
m_psectionHeader = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((DWORD_PTR)m_pntHeader + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS) + (40 * 4)); // pointing to desired section header

LPVOID m_pvFileBuffer = NULL; 

SYSTEM_INFO si;
GetSystemInfo(&si);
printf("Virtual size %d\n",m_psectionHeader->Misc.VirtualSize);
int m_pageNumber = (m_psectionHeader->Misc.VirtualSize / si.dwPageSize);
if ((m_psectionHeader->Misc.VirtualSize % si.dwPageSize) > 0)
{
    m_pageNumber++;
    printf("pages : %i\n",m_pageNumber);
    printf("page size: %i\n", si.dwPageSize);
}

m_pvFileBuffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, (si.dwPageSize*m_pageNumber), MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_NOACCESS);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_pageNumber*si.dwPageSize; i += si.dwPageSize)
    {
        // we need a char* to pointer arithmetic with
        char* p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(m_pvFileBuffer);

        // reserve the ith page
        VirtualAlloc(p + i, si.dwPageSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    }
printf("lpvoid : %d",m_pvFileBuffer);
m_ptr = Rva2Offset(m_psectionHeader->VirtualAddress,m_psectionHeader,m_pntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections);

memcpy(m_pvFileBuffer,(DWORD*)m_ptr,m_psectionHeader->Misc.VirtualSize);
//memcpy(&m_pvFileBuffer,&m_ptr,m_psectionHeader->Misc.VirtualSize); // buffer over-run here
//VirtualFree(m_pvFileBuffer,m_psectionHeader->Misc.VirtualSize,MEM_RELEASE);
cin.get();
return m_pvFileBuffer;
 }
```

Here is the error:

```
First-chance exception at 0x002f16f3 in Stub.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00002a00. A buffer overrun has occurred in Stub.exe which has corrupted the program's internal state. Press Break to debug the program or Continue to terminate the program. For more details please see Help topic 'How to debug Buffer Overrun Issues'.
```

Also, the code breaks and goes to here:

[image: Code break]

I have a suspicion that I am attempting to read non-readable memory (section's data), however I am unsure,

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Showing your error message would help.     To to debug: Ideas: memcpy_s() helps protect the destination from over running, but it and memcpy() do not validate the src & dest pointers.  Validate the src by making a for loop dereferencing each byte at a time, do same with the destination.

Answer (score 0):

```
int m_pageNumber = (m_psectionHeader->Misc.VirtualSize / si.dwPageSize);
```

This rounds the size down to the number of pages possibly minus one. Are you sure that VirtualSize is a multiple of dwPageSize? because later you do:

```
memcpy(m_pvFileBuffer,(DWORD*)m_ptr,m_psectionHeader->Misc.VirtualSize);
```

and if VirtualSize is not a multiple of dwPageSize then you are going to far in the memcpy().

I do not know the API well enough to know whether the VirtualAlloc() properly allocates all the pages, but the other problem could be that the function does not do what you're thinking so writing in those pages creates a memory violation.

Just in case, the division should be like this if VirtualSize may not be a multiple of dwPageSize():

```
int m_pageNumber = ((m_psectionHeader->Misc.VirtualSize + si.dwPageSize - 1) / si.dwPageSize);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I appreciate it. However I still get errors through the memcpy function, I'm going to attempt to debug it.